# Firestore add generates same document id for two documents?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

We are migrating data from sql database to Firestore. For some time was working fine, but yesterday we noticed bunch of errors on add document. We want autogenerated document ids. We are using Admin sdk, with nodejs, adding documents like this:

```
this.db.collection(`orgs`).doc(`${pkOrgId}`).collection(`people`).add(person);
```

Are we processing too fast? Is there a limit how many document ids can be issued per second or something? We do retry on error, but it feels strange that we are getting same id for two add document requests.
This is the error we are getting, I did find this document id in given collection for an object that was in same batch as one that failed:

> Error: 6 ALREADY_EXISTS: Document already exists: projects/xyzddsdsdsds/databases/(default)/documents/orgs/hlwYVvSIczwltsqtorNc/people/xqP9Jtzs3CWGBbCBiXEt

Comment: Firebase auto-generated document IDs are UUIDs. While it is theoretically possible that two calls to `add()` generate the same ID, it is statistically *incredibly* unlikely. If you can reproduce this problem, can you edit your question to show a snippet of code that any of us can run that reproduces the error?

Comment: We just see it under load, not able to reproduce it otherwise.

Comment: Can you give more details of how this processing is happening? Like, is this one instance of the admin SDK doing all the processing or multiple concurrent threads of it, how many documents are we talking about here, etc.